# drop down lists in php using cookies

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

```
<?php
$i=1;
//echo '<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post"  action="<?PHP $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF' ]
echo '<form>'; 
echo "<select name='dropdown' id=$i onchange='myFunction()'><option>Select one...</option>";

echo '<option value="horse">horse</option>';
echo '<option value="hor">hor</option>';


echo '</select>';

    echo '</form>';
    $i++;
    echo '<form>'; 
    echo "<select name='dropdown' id=$i onchange='myFunction()'><option>Select one...</option>";

    echo '<option value="por">por</option>';
    echo '<option value="voi">voi</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '<p id="demo"></p>
    <script type ="text/javascript">

    function myFunction()
    {
        var k=2;
        var x=document.getElementById(k);
        var y=x.options[x.selectedIndex];
        if(y){
            document.cookie=\'name=\'+y.value;
            alert(y.value);
        }

    }
    </script>';
    $var=$_COOKIE["name"];
    echo $var;
    ?>
```

Comment: can you add some description?

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Are you trying to set the default value of the combo to the cookie value ? You must check the value for each line, example : `echo '<option value="por" '.($_COOKIE['name']==='por' ? 'SELECTED' : '').'>por</option>';`

Comment: i have more than one drop down list in a single page, so when i try to fetch the selected value, using variable $i for id, i get the value selected in the second drop down if $i is static or from the first otherwise.